# Armor of Agathys usage of Water

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components

The spell *Armor of Agathys* says:

> Components: V, S, M (a cup of water)

Does the cup of water get used up in the casting of the spell?

I have a player casting this over and over and I'm wondering if he has enough water.

Answer (score 8):

From [Spellcasting](https://www.5esrd.com/spellcasting), on material components:

> Casting some spells requires particular objects, specified in parentheses in the component entry. A character can use a component pouch or a spellcasting focus (found in “Equipment”) in place of the components specified for a spell. But if a cost is indicated for a component, a character must have that specific component before he or she can cast the spell.
>
> **If a spell states that a material component is consumed by the spell, the caster must provide this component for each casting of the spell.**
>
> A spellcaster must have a hand free to access a spell’s material components—or to hold a spellcasting focus—but it can be the same hand that he or she uses to perform somatic components.

Emphasis added.

Armor of Agathys does not say it consumes the water, so it does not.

Comment: oh, thank you. I totally was edition blending and almost posted an answer to the opposite effect.

Comment: A common problem when 3.P is still so popular. Maybe Pathfinder v2 will help us move on from the 3.5e days... and maybe someday I'll stop wishing we could use Windows XP still. Maybe...

Comment: Also worth mentioning is that if the caster has a focus he doesn't need the spell components that don't have a cost.